# SQL Select empty

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code in Oracle 11:

```
select xmlelement("foo", xmlagg(xmlelement("bar",myValues))) from someTable where rownum = 0; --Changing the rownum from 0 should give me values
```

The output currently is: `<foo></foo>`

I would instead like this to return nothing, or null, when no rows are select. Otherwise it'll be a XMLtype with the aggregated data like how I have it above.

How would I be able to achieve this for the case when no rows are selected?

Comment: You might consider a decode function or a novalue function that would check for if rownum = 0 or other criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case select:

`select case when count (*) != 0 then xmlelement("foo", xmlagg(xmlelement("bar",myValues))) end`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to `CLOB` using `getClobval` function and do a comparison.

```
SELECT
    xml
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            xmlelement("foo",xmlagg(xmlelement("bar",myvalues) ) ).getclobval() xml
        FROM
            sometable
    )
WHERE
    TO_CHAR(xml) != '<foo></foo>';
```